# Optimization of non-negative parameter matrix (with a column-sum term)

Tags: derivatives, optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have a matrix of parameters $\boldsymbol{X}$, with $F$ rows and $K$ columns, where each parameter is non-negative ($x_{fk} \geq 0$). I want to optimize this function:
\begin{align}
arg\max_{_X} \sum_k \left(-a \ln(\beta + \sum_{f} x_{fk}) + \sum_f c_{fk} \ln x_{fk} \right)\\
 = \sum_k -a \ln\left(\beta + \sum_{f} x_{fk}\right) + \sum_k\sum_f c_{fk} \ln x_{fk} 
\end{align}

where $\boldsymbol{C}$ is a $F \times K$ matrix of data.

A possible and straighforward solution is to take partial derivatives with respect to each $w_{fk}$. This gives me:

\begin{align}
x_{fk} = \frac{\beta + \sum_{i\neq f} x_{ik}}{a - c_{fk}} c_{fk}
\end{align}

**Derivation with matrices (or vectors)**

The above is just a core part of the function I want to optimize. Unfortunatelly thinks become very messy when deriving parameter by parameter. Thus, I wonder whether I can optimize this function using matrix notation (and eventually avoiding updates like the above where a parameter depends on all the parameters in the same column).

*What I do*:

Let $\ln \boldsymbol{\tilde{X}}$ be the matrix of containing the $\ln x_{fk}$ terms. Then I can re-express the function as:

$$
- a \ln(1 + \beta \sum_i x_i) \quad+\quad  tr(\boldsymbol{C}^T, \ln \boldsymbol{\tilde{X}})
$$

I think the derivative of the second term  with respect to $\boldsymbol{X}$is:
$$
tr(\boldsymbol{C}^T \frac{\partial}{\partial}\ln \boldsymbol{\tilde{X}})
$$
where the derivative of $\ln \boldsymbol{\tilde{X}}$ is a matrix with elements $1/x_{fk}$.

For the first term, I don't know know to proceed.

Alternatively, I tried also deriving with respect to each column of $\boldsymbol{X}$. The function would be:

\begin{align}
\sum_k - a \ln(1 + \beta \sum_i x_{ik}) + \boldsymbol{C}_{:,k}^T \ln \boldsymbol{X}_{:,k}
\end{align}

But still I'm not sure how to deal with the first term

**Question**: How can I optimize this function using matrix notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define two vectors whose elements are all equal to unity $$u\in{\mathbb R}^{F}, \,\,\,\,v\in{\mathbb R}^{K}$$ then summations can be replaced by multiplications by these vectors.

The following definitions will be useful 
$$\eqalign{
B &= \frac{\beta uv^T}{u^Tu} &= \frac{\beta uv^T}{F} \cr
y &= X^Tu &\implies y^T = u^TX \cr
p &= \frac{C^Tu}{a} &\implies p^T = \frac{u^TC}{a} \cr
P &= {\rm Diag}(p) \cr
}$$
Let's also define the notations used for

- the regular/matrix product $(AB)$
- the inner/Frobenius product $(A:B=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)\,)$
- the elementwise/Hadamard product $(A\odot B)$
- the elementwise/Hadamard division $(A\oslash B)\,$ or $\,(\frac{A}{B})$

Now write the cost function in matrix form, and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
J &= C:\log(X) - av^T:\log(u^T(X+B)) \cr\cr
dJ &= C:d\log(X) - av^T:d\log(u^T(X+B)) \cr
   &= C:{dX}\oslash{X} - av^T:{u^TdX}\oslash{u^T(X+B)} \cr
   &= C:{dX}\oslash{X} - av^T:{u^TdX}\oslash{(y^T+\beta v^T)} \cr
   &= {C}\oslash{X}:dX - {av^T}\oslash(y^T+\beta v^T):u^TdX \cr
   &= {C}\oslash{X}:dX - au\Big[v^T\oslash(y^T+\beta v^T)\Big]:dX \cr
   &= \Bigg[\frac{C}{X} - au\Bigg(\frac{v^T}{y^T+\beta v^T}\Bigg)\Bigg]:dX \cr
\cr
\nabla J &= \frac{C}{X} - au\Bigg(\frac{v^T}{y^T+\beta v^T}\Bigg) \cr
\cr
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for $X$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{C}{X} &= u\Bigg(\frac{av^T}{y^T+\beta v^T}\Bigg) \cr
C &= X\odot u\Bigg(\frac{av^T}{y^T+\beta v^T}\Bigg) \cr
  &= X\,\,{\rm Diag}\Bigg(\frac{av}{y+\beta v}\Bigg) \cr
  &= X\,\,{\rm Diag}(av)\,\,{\rm Diag}(y+\beta v)^{-1} \cr
  &= a\,X(Y+\beta I)^{-1} \cr
\cr
X &= \frac{1}{a}\,C\,(Y+\beta I) \cr
  &= \frac{C}{a}\,\bigg({\rm Diag}(u^TX)+\beta I\bigg) \cr
}$$
This is almost the result we want.

Multiply by $u^T$ to produce a recursive equation for $y$
$$\eqalign{
u^TX  &= \frac{u^TC}{a}\,\bigg({\rm Diag}(u^TX)+\beta I\bigg) \cr
y^T  &= p^T\bigg({\rm Diag}(y^T)+\beta I\bigg) \cr
y &= {\rm Diag}(y)\,p + \beta p \cr
  &= y\odot p + \beta p \cr
\cr
y\odot(v-p) &= \beta p \cr
\cr
\frac{y}{\beta} &= \frac{p}{v-p} \cr
\frac{Y}{\beta} &= {\rm Diag}\bigg(\frac{p}{v-p}\bigg) = P(I-P)^{-1} \cr
\cr
}$$
Substituting this into the previous result yields the optimal value for the parameter matrix
$$\eqalign{
 X &= \Big(\frac{\beta}{a}\Big)\,C\,\Big(\frac{Y}{\beta}+I\Big) \cr
   &= \Big(\frac{\beta}{a}\Big)\,C\,\Big(P(I-P)^{-1}+I\Big) \cr
   &= \Big(\frac{\beta}{a}\Big)\,C\,\Big(P+(I-P)\Big)\,(I-P)^{-1} \cr
   &= \Big(\frac{\beta}{a}\Big)\,C\,(I-P)^{-1} \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, @greg. The first time you write $\nabla J = $ ... shouldn't there be a trace?

Comment: A trace would produce a scalar value, whereas the gradient of a scalar wrt a matrix needs to be matrix-valued.