# Gradient with logarithm of matrix $ \nabla_{\boldsymbol{X}} tr\left(\boldsymbol{a} \ln(\boldsymbol{u}^T(\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{X}))\right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let 
$$\boldsymbol{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{F\times K} \qquad \boldsymbol{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{F\times K}
$$
and
$$
\boldsymbol{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times 1}
\qquad \boldsymbol{u} = \mathbb{1}_{F \times 1}
$$

Given this operation
$$
tr\left(\boldsymbol{a} \ln(\boldsymbol{u}^T(\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{W}))\right)
$$
I would like to understand its derivative with respect to $\boldsymbol{W}$, which, following [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189552/optimization-of-non-negative-parameter-matrix-with-a-column-sum-term) would give:

$$
\boldsymbol{u} \frac{\boldsymbol{a}^T}{\boldsymbol{u}^T (\boldsymbol{W} + \boldsymbol{B})}
$$

*Question:* May someone explain the steps and the properties used to arrive here?

**What I do**:

If I'm not wrong:
$$
\frac{\partial tr(F(\boldsymbol{X})}{\boldsymbol{X}} = f(\boldsymbol{X}) 
$$
Then I can ignore the trace. Then I would use a chain rule:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}}
\left(\boldsymbol{a} \ln(\boldsymbol{u}^T(\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{W}))\right) = \boldsymbol{a}^T \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}} \ln(\boldsymbol{u}^T(\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{W}))
$$

and now 
$$
\boldsymbol{a}^T
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}} \ln(\boldsymbol{u}^T(\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{W})) = 
\boldsymbol{a}^T
\frac{\boldsymbol{u}}{\boldsymbol{u}^T(\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{W})}
$$
where the division is element-wise.

I've seen, in the linked answer, that the authors uses $\boldsymbol{u}^T\partial\boldsymbol{X}$ but I don't understand where it comes from (neither what $\partial{\boldsymbol{X}}$ means)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the function as 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= a^T:\log(u^T(B+W)) \cr
}$$ where colon denotes the inner/Frobenius product.

Take the differential of the function
$$\eqalign{
df &= a^T:d\log(u^T(B+W)) \cr
   &= a^T:\frac{u^TdW}{u^T(B+W)} \cr
   &= \frac{a^T}{u^T(B+W)}:u^TdW \cr
   &= u\frac{a^T}{u^T(B+W)}:dW \cr
}$$
So the gradient is (as you anticipated)
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} &= u\frac{a^T}{u^T(B+W)} \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks @lynn. Can you add some explanation on (a) when you put $u^TdW$ to the right and when you pass it to the left? (b) I freak out every time I see dW standling alone, I get the mechanics but not the inuition. Is there some basic reference, tutorial, exercizes, or whatever to get familiarized with this?

Comment: A simple rule is that both of the matrices involved in a Frobenius or Hadamard product, or Hadamard division, must have the same shape, i.e. the same number of rows and columns, in order for the operation to be valid.

Comment: Another rule to keep in mind is that the Frobenius product is just a convenient infix notation for the trace $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$and the trace has a number of well-known properties regarding the transposition and rearrangement of its arguments.  Work through those properties using the Frobenius syntax if you want to get comfortable with the mechanics.